# using ifstream from a stringstream converted in a string

Tags: c++, ifstream, stringstream

I really don't understand why if I use *f.open(filename.c_str(),ios::in)* works only if filename is a string defined as a string type, but not if filename is been converted from a stringstream type.

I need stringstream type, because I have to open different folders, so I use the program to create the wanted adresses.

Thankyou your cooperation.

```
using namespace std;
//c++ -o iso iso.cpp `root-config --cflags --glibs`
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n_gruppo, n_righe;

    cout << "write the number of the folder: " << endl;
    cin >> n_gruppo;
    int num_vol[6]={1,2,3,5,7,10};

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        //combining the string
        stringstream ss;    
        ss <<"/home/student/isoterma"<<n_gruppo<<"/pressione_vol"<<num_vol[i]<<".txt"<<endl;
        string filename = ss.str();//conversion sstream in string
        cout << filename << endl;

        double sumsq = 0, sum = 0, s;
        //cicle of reading
        ifstream f ;
        f.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);//ricorda di mettere '.c_str()' infondo se è una stringa

        for (int io = 0; io < n_righe ; io++)
        {
            f >> s;
            cout << "value N° " << io << " is" << s << endl;
            sum += s;
            sumsq += pow(s,2);
        }
        f.close();

      }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can this clarify things? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034834/is-there-issue-will-stringstream-str-c-str

Comment: So you're saying that open(ss.str().c_str()) does not work? Or did you try to store the const char * from the temporary object returned from str(), and use it later?

Comment: What do you mean by "works only if"? *How* does it not work when the precondition is not satisfied? Does it not compile? What behaviour does it have? What behaviour did you expect? In any case, create a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried to define the adress of a folder as a string(es. string s = "/home/student/folder1/file1.txt"), without combining the name of the folder and the name of the file (es. strigstream ss; ss<<"/home/student/folder"<<n_folder<<"/file"<<n_file<<".txt"<<endl;
        string s = ss.str();), and the program compiled correctly.
But, if I use stringstream to combine the string, the program compiles in a wrong way: I mean, it reads the same number in each line of each file. I also verified it with f.good, and f.fail: the cicle "for" does not read correctly the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three issues with the code you posted:

1. In writing to the `stringstream`, you **should not include** the `std::endl` at the end. Otherwise, the resulting string for the `filename` includes an extra newline character at the end, which most likely caused the file open to fail. Therefore, replace:

   ```
   ss <<"/home/student/isoterma"<<n_gruppo<<"/pressione_vol"<<num_vol[i]<<".txt"<<endl;
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   ss <<"/home/student/isoterma"<<n_gruppo<<"/pressione_vol"<<num_vol[i]<<".txt";
   ```

   This will most likely fix your problem. Also consider using `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::stringstream` here since you are only writing, not reading.
2. Your variable `n_righe` is being used uninitialized. In your actual code, you probably have this initialized to the number of lines in each of your files. However, you should consider using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035674/how-to-read-line-by-line-or-a-whole-text-file-at-once) to read all the lines in your files.
3. You should always check to see if your `ifstream` is opened successfully before reading from it. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206816/ifstream-check-if-opened-successfully) for that.